# jQuery fade through a list of elements then restart at the beginning

Tags: jquery, list, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I have a slideshow of sorts- clicking on an image fades it out and fades in the next via jQuery's `.next()` When it hits the end of the list, it doesn't skip back to the beginning (naturally) because there's no element that's next.

What can I add to my code to start it back at the beginning after it gets to the end?

Here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/gBw9j/6/

Thank you!

EDIT: changed the fade out/fade in function to fniish the fade out before fading in the next element

Here is my Current Code

```
$('#two, #three, #four').hide();
$('.slide').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut(600, function(){ $this.next().fadeIn(600); });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simple fix.

hide #two and #three with css

```
#two,#three {display: none;}
```

and change Jquery to this

```
$('.slide').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().next().fadeIn();
    $(this).insertAfter('.slide:last');
});
```

basically after you hide the first one move it to the end.

updated live example: http://jsfiddle.net/XeCUf/

note: you do not have to remove

```
$('#two,#three).hide()
```

but i find it to be a best practice to let CSS do its job, and use a minimal amount of scripting for presentation.

**UPDATE**

per your modified question I have modified my answer

```
$('#two, #three, #four').hide(); // <- consider moving to css
$('.slide').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut(600, function() {
        $this.next().fadeIn(600);
        $this.insertAfter('.slide:last');
    });
```

});

and the updated live example : http://jsfiddle.net/XbY3C/

Comment: works perfectly.. but forgot to post the newer version of my fade out/ fade in function. edited my post with the correct function

Comment: @technopeasant, I have updated my answer per your updated code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numOfItemsToFade = 1,
    numOfItems = $('ul li').length;
showList();
function showList() {
  $('ul li:nth-child('+numOfItemsToFade+')').fadeIn(500, function(){
    numOfItemsToFade++;
    if(numOfItemsToFade<= numOfItems){
      showList();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but this seems to work:

```
$('#two, #three').hide();
$('.slide').click(function(){
    var $next = $(this).fadeOut().next();
    if ($next.length > 0) {
        $next.fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("div.slide:first").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this??

```
$('#two, #three').hide();
$('.slide').click(function() {
    var $next = $(this).next();
    if ($next.length === 0) {
        $next = $(this).parent().first(); // or some other way of finding the first
    }
    $next().fadeIn();
});
```

Good luck~